# Most common value from multiple colums in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, statistics

I have a series of data in an irregular number of columns and I need to determine the most common value from split sections across multiple columns using pandas. An example of what I mean is if I had information of what kind of cheese my coworkers had with their lunches each day:

```
Idx Name   Cheese1   Cheese2   Cheese3
0   Evan   Gouda     NaN       NaN
1   John   Cheddar   Havarti   Blue
2   Evan   Cheddar   Gouda     NaN
3   John   Havarti   Swiss     NaN
```

I'm looking for some kind of functionality that will give the resulting pivot table:

```
Name    Cheese    Pct
Evan    Gouda     .66
John    Havarti   .4
```

I also don't know how many columns will need to be included each time I run the script, only that they're all of the format "Cheese"+index. If John shows up with four cheeses the next day, I will need to add a fourth column and the analysis script needs to be able to handle that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import io
import pandas as pd

data = io.StringIO("""\
Idx Name   Cheese1   Cheese2   Cheese3
0   Evan   Gouda     NaN       NaN
1   John   Cheddar   Havarti   Blue
2   Evan   Cheddar   Gouda     NaN
3   John   Havarti   Swiss     NaN
4   Rick   NaN       NaN       NaN
""")
df = pd.read_csv(data, delim_whitespace=True)

def top_cheese(g):
    cheese_cols = [col for col in g.columns if col.startswith('Cheese')]
    try:
        out = (g[cheese_cols].stack().value_counts(normalize=True)
                             .reset_index().iloc[0])
        out.index = ['Cheese', 'Pct']
        return out
    except IndexError:
        return pd.Series({'Cheese': 'None', 'Pct': 0})


output = df.groupby('Name').apply(top_cheese)
print(output)
```

Output:

```
       Cheese       Pct
Name                   
Evan    Gouda  0.666667
John  Havarti  0.400000
Rick     None  0.000000
```

Comment: You missed an opportunity to name the function `big_cheese`

Comment: This works, but it breaks when all of the people have the same most common cheese. Instead it gives the name as a column header and not an index. Is there any way to fix that?

Comment: I kind-of fixed it by using a try-except statement to either get the index or the column name, but it's janky and I'd like a better solution if anyone has one.

Comment: This worked. I don't actually care about the droplevel, but thanks for putting that in there regardless! I also changed the function to try/except the return statement, since some of my coworkers do not bring cheese at all, so all of their rows are empty. I included: `except: return pd.Series(data = [0], index = ['None']).reset_index()` and it works great.

Comment: One last update. Changing `.iloc[[0]]` for `.iloc[0]` returns a `Series` and avoids having to drop a level. Moved indexing inside `top_cheese()`. Added your `try/except` logic. And what's going on with Rick? No cheese? Oh, the Humanity!

Answer (score 0):

Recently, I've been using `R` quite a bit and there I would solve this like:

```R
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

x <- fread('
Idx Name   Cheese1   Cheese2   Cheese3
0   Evan   Gouda     NaN       NaN
1   John   Cheddar   Havarti   Blue
2   Evan   Cheddar   Gouda     NaN
3   John   Havarti   Swiss     NaN', na = 'NaN')

gather(x, , Cheese, matches('Cheese'), na.rm = T) %>%
  group_by(Name, Cheese) %>%
  summarise(n = n()) %>%
  group_by(Name) %>%
  mutate(p = n/sum(n)) %>%
  filter(p == max(p)) %>%
  select(-n)
```

Which outputs:

```R
   Name  Cheese         p
  (chr)   (chr)     (dbl)
1  Evan   Gouda 0.6666667
2  John Havarti 0.4000000
```

I was interested to see how a similar thing would look like in Pandas. This is what I came up with:

```
import io
import pandas as pd

x = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO('''
Idx Name   Cheese1   Cheese2   Cheese3
0   Evan   Gouda     NaN       NaN
1   John   Cheddar   Havarti   Blue
2   Evan   Cheddar   Gouda     NaN
3   John   Havarti   Swiss     NaN'''), delim_whitespace=True)

tidy = pd.melt(x, ['Idx', 'Name'], value_name='Cheese').dropna()
tidy = tidy.groupby(['Name', 'Cheese']).size().reset_index(name='n')
tidy['p'] = tidy.groupby('Name')['n'].transform(lambda n: n/sum(n))
tidy[tidy['p'] == tidy.groupby('Name')['p'].transform('max')].drop('n', 1)
```

Which outputs:

```
   Name   Cheese         p
1  Evan    Gouda  0.666667
4  John  Havarti  0.400000
```

Definitely not as clean as `R`, but maybe someone more acquainted with Pandas can weigh in how to improve this.